# Setting flat pages in admin model

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I just installed flat pages app for django and trying to create a flat pages from admin .
[image]

So after I create  a page in admin there is an option view on site and when I click on it I am getting Page not found

what am I missing?When I set my name to /pages/overview/ I still get page not found

[image]

Comment: Have you completed step 3 of the [installation instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/)?

Comment: Yes I did, else wise it would not show pages in URL patterns I have tried.(second screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the pages URLs with a prefix of `^pages/`, which means you need to add that prefix to your request URL. E.g., for a page that you have configured as `/help/overview/`, you would access it from `http://localhost:8000/pages/help/overview/`.

You either need to request all your page URLs with a `/pages/` prefix, or use one of the other methods described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf):

> You can also set it up as a “catchall” pattern. In this case, it is important to place the pattern at the end of the other urlpatterns:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.flatpages import views
>
> # Your other patterns here
> urlpatterns += [
>     url(r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', views.flatpage),
> ]
> ```
>
> Another common setup is to use flat pages for a limited set of known pages and to hard code the urls, so you can reference them with the url template tag:
>
> ```
> urlpatterns += [
>     url(r'^about-us/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about-us/'}, name='about'),
>     url(r'^license/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/license/'}, name='license'),
> ]
> ```

Finally you can also use the [`FlatPageFallbackMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-middleware).

Comment: Thank you @solarissmoke the thing is when I input in a form url with pages 

I get an error -  No FlatPage matches the given query.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify. If you save the page with a URL of `/help/overview/`, then you can access it at `http://localhost:8000/pages/help/overview/`. Don't change the URL on the page itself.